# Tree of linked lists

Tags: data-structures

My question is, does this have a proper name. (ie.  has it been invented before)?

A (file-efficient) tree structure configured as a tree of linked lists, in the following fashion:[image]

As can be seen, instead of each node having to remember a 'list' of children, it lists one child and this links to other siblings using a linked list. This way the space requirement for all nodes is constant (2).

Comment: I've seen this before, or at least very similar structures. The Lisp programmer's way of representing a tree is quite similar.

Comment: I see. (http://gajon.org/trees-linked-lists-common-lisp/) but only a description is given, not a name, as far as I read. Could it be called a 'Cons' tree, or is Cons a typical Lisp word?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a representation of a k-ary tree as a binary tree, known as [left child - right sibling binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_child-right_sibling_binary_tree).

Comment: Beat me to it.  This was exactly what I was going to say.